# Anchor styling having issues

Tags: css

I have a styling done which is as follows

```
/*------------this css is an internal css in the html page-------------*/

<style>
.rating_star
  {
      background-image: url('<?php echo base_url();?>assets/front_assets/images/star_hv.gif');
  }

.rating_star hover
  {
      background-image: url('<?php echo base_url();?>assets/front_assets/images/star.gif');
  }
</style>
```

and here is the HTML part:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="
        var i='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/front_assets/images/loading.gif';
        var load = document.createElement('img');
        load.setAttribute('src', i);

        $('#rate').html(load);
        $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>rating/rate'
             {'star':1,'item_slug':$('#item_slug').val()},
               function(data){$('#rate').html(data););" class="rating_star">&nbsp;
</a>
```

The problem is that I can't see any image, even if I hover over the a `href`, I see no change.

Comment: Are the two spaces the only content in the `a`? Then it just may be too small; I don't see where you try to set a size on it. Otherwise, check if `base_url` returns what you want it to return. Does it end with a slash?

Comment: And you misspelled the hovering selector; that should have been `.rating_star:hover` with a colon. With a space it means "a `hover` element inside the `rating_star` one".

Comment: Can be closed as either "unclear" or "lacking an [mcve]".